# Calendar.MONTH gives wrong value

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to get the actual month from the `Calendar` using the following:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();          
String time = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

According the system settings "Settings --> Date & Time" actual month is 10 while `get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns 09.

Comment: You need to subtract 1 from it since months go from 0..11

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Keep in mind that months values start from `0`, so `October` is actually month number `9`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH

Answer (score 9):

`Calendar.MONTH` returns month which is zero based that is why it is giving 1 less than actual month 
Add 1 to get correct value

```
String time = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Calendar.MONTH`

returns

```
0 for 1st month (jan)
1 for 2nd month (feb)
.
.
11 for 12th month (dec)
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

So change your code to

```
String time = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);// added 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.MONTH value starts from 0 to 11 not 1 to 12.

You may check the value of Calendar.JANUARY is 0 not 1.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying

```
@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int day) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), month+1 + "/" + day  + "/" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
calDate = month+1 + "/" + day + "/" + year; }
});
```

Comment: Concatenating strings to make dates is unsafe for internationalization and a terrible practice. Please use the system library date formatters.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    public void DateDialog(){

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            int Month;
            Month=monthOfYear+1;
            fromDate.setText(year + "-" + Month + "-" + dayOfMonth);
        }};
    DatePickerDialog dpDialog=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
    dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(mcalendar.getTimeInMillis());
    dpDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the existing answers? Some comments might be useful.