# DatePickerDialog month name shows M+0+Month number

Tags: android, dialog

I am using DatePickerDialog. But month name are showing wrong, i.e. instead of January 2019 it is showing 2019 M01 and February as 2019 M02 and so on.
My problem is that default view for calendarView is showing the month numbers like that, i am not changing or setting anything in this views, normally it must show something like : 2019 January.

How can i fix this issue?

My Layout:

[MY LAYOUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvUYR.jpg)

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calender"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"/>
```

My Code:

```
  CalendarView calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calender);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            saveDate(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348065/calendar-month-gives-wrong-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calendar.MONTH gives wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348065/calendar-month-gives-wrong-value)

Comment: @nitinkumarp no im not

Comment: @elarcoiris im using calendarView, not calendar itself

Comment: @Ankitihelpersharma didnt help

Comment: Using an overridden `Locale` in your app?

Comment: I have tested with above code and no issue found. Try to comment other operation on calendar view if so you are doing in activity.

Comment: @laalto yes i did, and i removed it, but still the same

Comment: @Ankitihelpersharma i did nothing more with calendar and calendarview in my app, the problem is that it works correctly in other apps, i want to know what affects calendarview to behave like that

Comment: Try to create new project and test whether same issue occur or not

Comment: did you figure out why is happening?

Answer (score 1):

this is happened due to **misconfiguration of Locale** you must set Locale to **en** to get January like month

the following code will use to set locale

```
fun setLocale(context: Context, language: String): Context {
        persist(language, context)
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            updateResources(context, language)
        } else updateResourcesLegacy(context, language)
    }

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private fun updateResources(context: Context, language: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val configuration = context.resources.configuration
    configuration.setLocale(locale)
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration)
}

private fun updateResourcesLegacy(context: Context, language: String): Context {
    val locale = Locale(language)
    Locale.setDefault(locale)
    val resources = context.resources
    val configuration = resources.configuration
    configuration.locale = locale
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.displayMetrics)
    return context
}
```

Somewhere in your base Activity

```
override fun attachBaseContext(newBase: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(setLocale(context, "en"))//or other language
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, mate, I was also setting the wrong language ```(english instead of 'en')```.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Calendar calendar;
    CalendarView calendarView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.MAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2019);


        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);


        calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);


        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                String msg = "Selected date Day: " + i2 + " Month : " + (i1 + 1) + " Year " + i;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });


    }
}
```